# Convert datepicker date time to php date time

Tags: php

Currently I'm using jquery datepicker that support date and time.

The return value is string

**return value**

> "Fri Apr 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"

I wan to convert the above string to php date time to store into database .

I just need date time and timezone .

Comment: So have you looked at [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)?

Comment: @MarkBaker I already tried that but the error unexpected 'CreateFromFormat'

Comment: Then what version of PHP are you running? The `createFromFormat()` method has been available since PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to remove information, that breaks conversion:

```
preg_replace('/( \(.*)$/','','Fri Apr 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)');
```

Results in:

> 'Fri Apr 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0800'

what you can convert to timestamp using `strtotime()`:

```
$datetime = "Fri Apr 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";
$datetime =  preg_replace('/( \(.*)$/','',$datetime);
$timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s \G\M\TP', $timestamp);
```

I'm GMT+2 so I receive `2015-04-10 06:00:00 GMT+02:00`. Further formatting depents on your desired `date()` formatting.

If you want to keep original time, heres the trick:

```
$datetime = "Fri Apr 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";
$datetime =  preg_replace('/( \(.*)$/','',$datetime);

$date = new DateTime($datetime);
$zone = $date->getTimezone();

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' GMT' .  $zone->getName();
```

gives `2015-04-10 12:00:00 GMT+08:00`.